# First Scheduled Stack Exchange 0 A.D. Game

Tags: discussion, community, fun

We over at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) have decided to schedule a game of [0 A.D.](http://play0ad.com/) this Sunday. Someone suggested that I mention it over here, so that's what I'm doing :)

### Details

For those who are interested, here are the details:

**Date / Time:** Oct. 13, 2013 at 5PM EDT
 
[[click to view in other timezones]](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=Stack+Exchange+0+A.D.+Game&iso=20131013T14&p1=1085&ah=7)
**Hostname:** `home.quickmediasolutions.com`
**Map:** Azure Coast 1

Note that there is a limit on the number of players (eight) so come early (ten to fifteen minutes before the start of the game) to ensure you get a spot. The game will run until someone emerges victorious or seven hours have passed - whichever occurs first.

Comments indicating a desire to participate are welcome!

Comment: [More background here.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7418/anyone-interested-in-a-regularly-scheduled-multiplayer-game-of-0-a-d?cb=1)

Comment: Never actually finished a game of 0 A.D. before, but if there's space for me, I'm open to try :D

Comment: [Summary posted here.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7467/5)